# MySql Checking If exists from two fields by OR operator

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to check if exists by using or operator from two fields and get the `ID` if exists.But I am getting false by my function.

```
public static function exists(){
    $id = Helper::getUserID();
    $session_id = Helper::getSessionId();
    global $wpdb;
    $count = $wpdb->get_row(
                $wpdb->prepare(
                    "SELECT FROM `". self::cartTableName() ."` WHERE `user_id` = '%d' OR `session_id` = '%s'", intval($id), $session_id 
                )
            );
    if($count > 0){ 
        return true; 
    }else{ 
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Other classes with respective methods are okay.
But when i am running through this its not working (I mean Updating) ,rather inserting new.

```
if(self::exists()){
  // Update
}else{
  // insert
}
```

Also How can I get ID or IDS if exists?

Comment: Looks like the placeholders shouldn't be quoted, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/.

Comment: Did that but not works

Comment: `$wpdb->get_row(` might also not be correct, not sure. I don't wordpress, might want to wait for someone with more experience. Without the `or` this was working?

Comment: Before `FROM` you need to provide list of columns to select or use `*`

Comment: try SELECT * FROM